# Perform a double click on single click of a button

Tags: android, button

I have a button and when I click on that button it should automatically double click another button and perform a whatever should happen on the second buttons doubleclick.

Comment: you can use myButton.performClick();

Comment: myButton.performClick() clicks only once I need double click

Comment: use twise myButton.performClick();

Comment: tried it does not work